# Assign function keys to umlauts

Tags: keyboard, keybindings

I'm using Apple's wired keyboard with number pad.

[image: keyboard]

Above the number pad there are 4 unassigned function keys (<kbd>F16</kbd> to <kbd>F19</kbd>) which I would like to assign to the German umlauts <kbd>ä</kbd>, <kbd>ö</kbd>, <kbd>ü</kbd> and the sharp s <kbd>ß</kbd>.

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Not sure you can... but isn't it quicker to do it the 'regular' way, Opt/U, vowel for ä ö ü or just Opt/S for ß ? And what about upper case Ä Ö Ü ?

Comment: I don't think that would be quicker. That's what I use right now and it's a pain. Regarding capital umlauts, the function keys should respond to a pressed shift key the same way as all letters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be realizable with a -> Service. Such Automator Services are quite fast...but too slow for a smooth typing flow. However, there are third-party hotkey managers that are suitable for this.

- *Butler*: not updated for a long time, but very powerful and fast (and
  free)
- *BetterTouchTool*: quick and easy to use
- *Alfred*: might be too slow
- and many more...

With Butler you can execute text directly (!), with the others you might need an AppleScript. Open the *Script-Editor* to get the IDs for the umlauts:

```
id of "Ü"
```

The necessary Applescript for "Ü" would then look like this:

```
tell application "System Events" to keystroke (string id 220)
```

Assign e.g. shift-F19 (because of capitalization)

Comment: Just installed BetterTouchTool. How do I use it to bind function keys to umlauts?

Comment: Installation guide:

Comment: Installation guide: [link] (https://docs.bettertouchtool.net/docs/installation.html) Setting up a new gesture: [link] https://docs.bettertouchtool.net/docs/preferences_new_gesture.html  ...open BTT preferences -> Gestures , choose "Keyboard". Select on the right part of the window "Application: Global" and in the lower part of the window "+Add a new shortcut". Click to record a shortcut. Choose Trigger Predefined Action: Controlling other Applications -> Run AppleScript (async in background). Insert the AppleScript code

Comment: I ended up recording e.g. `F16` to trigger `alt + u` and then chose "Attach Additional Action" that triggers `a` which following the first action macOS converts to `ä`. The same works for `ö` and `ü`. For `ß`, simply trigger `alt + s` with no attached action.